# script tag inside another script tag not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, node.js

I want to load a script inside another script but it is returning an error

**code**

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         ----------//code for finding the device
       if(device=='mobile'){
       <script src="{{ url('----') }}"></script>
       }else{
       <script src="{{ url('-----') }}"></script>
      }
    });
    </script>
```

**Error:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

**I have tried solutions like:**

1)

```
<script>
    ...some other script...
&nbsp;/script>
```

2)

```
<script>
   {{html "</sc"+"ript>"}}
```

Comment: This is not how you conditionally load JS code. If you need to do this, read up on jQuery's `$.getScript()`, however I'd suggest loading different logic for mobile/desktop platforms shows a badly designed system. Your code base should be built in such a way that it works for all platforms.

Comment: What you wanna do?

Comment: You can try by including the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `document.write()` for this:

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url('----') }}"></script>');
```

> if you want to use jQuery then you can use another tricky way

```js
 if(device=='mobile'){
 $('#deviceJs').attr('src','mobile.js');
 } else {
 $('#deviceJs').attr('src','desktop.js');
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="deviceJs" src=""></script>
```